# Locust results not getting copied

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, locust

I'm able to get locust results in logfile but when trying with csv, it doesn't seem to work.

example that works :
*locust /locust/tests.py --host=http://127.0.0.1 -f locust_file.py --logfile=/locust/locust_log.log --master*

example that doesn't seem to work :
*locust /locust/tests.py --host=http://127.0.0.1 -f locust_file.py --master --no-web --csv=locust_log*

In another file tests.py, I am copying these csv logs to a bucket :
*aws s3 cp /locust/locust_log_stats.csv s3://locustresultlog/detailed-report/locust_log_eu.log*

which does not copy or show any logs. What could be wrong?

Comment: What version of locust are you using? In 1.0.3, there's no option `--no-web`. Perhaps you meant `--headless`. https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks, using aws s3 cp _/locust_log_distribution.csv_ just worked for me!